# 'caching_sha2_password' plugin failing on Windows

Tags: python, mysql, django, windows, web

I am currently trying to create a web application with Python's Django framework, while creating the databases through MySQL. I am running Windows 10, Django 2, Python3.6, and MySQL 8. I have tried many fixes but nothing seems to work. When I try to run test cases or run the server locally, I receive the same error: django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2059, "Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' cannot be loaded: The specified module could not be found.\r\n")

Comment: does anyone have solution for this issue?

Answer (score 2):

This problem occurs with MySQL 8 version, 
Either use MySQL 5.7 or use official driver from https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/ instead of using MySQL API driver from django https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/databases/#mysql-db-api-drivers site.

Answer (score 2):

You can run the MySql (>=8.0) container with the following as the *command* to be executed (actually, as a parameter for entrypoint.sh):

```
--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
```

For example,

```
docker run --rm -d -e MYSQL_DATABASE=test -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password mysql/mysql-server:latest --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
```

(Found the solution [here](https://github.com/mytardis/mytardis/issues/998).)